# GridGraph with diagonal edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have n x n `GridGraph` (or n x m), I trying to add diagonal edges for each square box automatically and then assign same weights to the diagonals, same weights to horizontal edges and same weights to Vertical edges.

[image: 9 X9 grid graph with cross edges]

I am using

```
n = 3;
G = GridGraph[{n, n}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
ce = {1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 4 <-> 8, 5 <-> 9, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 5 <-> 7, 6 <-> 8};
ea = EdgeAdd[G, ce]
GG = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[ea]];
```

Is there any way i can do this for any n x n grid without manually adding edges.

for 3x3 graph the upward edge is (n -> n + 4)  until n - 4 (5th node is the last to have this edge). And for downward edge its (n -> n + 2) until (n - 3).

I found one more code here which was adding the diagonal edges but the edges are added randomly.

```
n = 20;
G = GridGraph[{n, n}];
adjMgg = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[G]];
ind = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1/2], {n - 1, n - 1}] + 1;
crossedges = 
  Table[
    {(i - 1) n + j <-> (i - 1) n + j + n + 1,
     (i - 1) n + j + 1 <-> (i - 1) n + j + n}[[ind[[i, j]]]], 
    {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, n - 1}] // Flatten;
adjMdg = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[EdgeAdd[G, crossedges]]];
adjWeight = 300*adjMgg + (adjMdg - adjMgg) /. {0 -> ∞};
dg = 
  WeightedAdjacencyGraph[adjWeight, 
    GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {n, n}}, 
    VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
    VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.08, 0.35, 0.65], Bold, 10], 
    EdgeStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.7]], 
    VertexStyle -> RGBColor[0.08, 0.35, 0.65], 
    VertexSize -> 0.15, 
    ImagePadding -> 10, 
    ImageSize -> Scaled[0.8]];
Module[{i = 1, j = n^2, path}, 
  path = FindShortestPath[dg, i, 381];
  HighlightGraph[dg, PathGraph @ path, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
n = {3, 5};
g = GridGraph[{n, n}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
edAdd = Sort /@ UndirectedEdge @@@ Position[Outer[EuclideanDistance@## &, #, #, 1], 
                                            N@Sqrt@2] &@ GraphEmbedding@g // Union
EdgeAdd[g, edAdd]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I believe v10 has `DistanceMatrix` that should simplify this even more (by replacing the `Outer[ ...]`)

Answer (score 9):

[Mathematica has a built-in function :)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KingGraph.html)

```
GraphData[{"King", {m, n}}]

GraphData[{"King", {3, 7}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The downside is that this does not work for general arguments $n$ and $m$. For example, at the time of writing, `GraphData[{"King", {11, 11}}]` results in an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[diagGraph]
diagGraph[n_Integer] :=
 EdgeAdd[
   GridGraph[{n, n}, VertexLabels -> "Name"],
   Join[
    Table[i <-> i + n + 1, {i, Select[Range[1, n^2 - n], Mod[#, n] != 0 &]}],
    Table[i <-> i + n - 1, {i, Select[Range[2, n^2 - n + 1], Mod[#, n] != 1 &]}]
   ]
 ]

diagGraph[5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I just changed range equation to         Range[1, n^2-n] and Range[2, N^2-n+1]; this makes the graph universal you can use any number and generate n X n graph. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @NakulPadalkar Thank you for pointing that out, I forgot to change those out from a previous draft! I fixed them now.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Using `RelationGraph` (new in version 10.2) with `ChessboardDistance`:

```
ClearAll[ggF]
ggF[r_, c_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{v = Join @@ Array[{##} &, {c, r}]},
  RelationGraph[ChessboardDistance[v[[#]], v[[#2]]] == 1 &, 
   Range[r c], o, VertexCoordinates -> v, VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
```

Example:

```
ggF[4, 7, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], ImageSize -> 500,  
 VertexStyle -> Yellow, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Blue, 16], 
 VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[diagGridGraph];
diagGridGraph[n_Integer, m_Integer, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{v = Range[n m], mat, edges},
  mat = Transpose[Reverse@Partition[Reverse@v, n]];
  edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@ 
        ComponentMeasurements[mat, "Neighbors", CornerNeighbors -> True]]];
  Graph[v, edges, GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {n, m}}, opts]]

diagGridGraph[4, 8, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> .3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

You will like this maybe

```
NearestNeighborGraph[GraphEmbedding@GridGraph[{5, 6}], 
 DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance]
```

[image: i]

Answer (score 1):

Create a grid of points:

```
pts = Tuples[{Range[4], Range[6]}];
```

Create a nearest neighbour graph with an appropriate cutoff distance.  At the same time, add edge weights as euclidean distances.

```
NearestNeighborGraph[pts, {All, 3/2}, 
 EdgeWeight -> {edge_ :> Apply[EuclideanDistance, edge]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = GridGraph[{5, 6}];

EdgeDelete[
 GraphPower[
  VertexReplace[grid, 
   Thread[VertexList[grid] -> GraphEmbedding@grid]], 
  2], _?(MemberQ[Abs[Subtract @@ #], 2.] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]